# my block xsl fo is too big and thus prevents the generation of pdf

Tags: xsl-fo

so here I have a block that contains a table that I get from my xml but this table is large and can not get into my pdf page, so what I want is when it can not enter wholemeent in my page it goes to the next page. thank you all

Comment: This is not enough information to answer your question.  Please provide (minimal) sample markup and possibly a screenshot so that we can see what the problem is.

Comment: If I understand correctly what your problem is, you probably have _keep properties_ (`keep-together`, `keep-with-next`, `keep-with-previous`) preventing the table to be split between pages.

Comment: no, i haven't this properties, sorry i can't show to you my code because i don't have it for this moment, monday i will post some part of my code to better clarify my problem

Comment: @ifurni yes it was it I had my nested block in a block that itself was nested in another block that was in keep-together.within-page = 'always'